# adView is not visible with wrap content

Tags: java, android, adview

In the XML layout, everything seems perfect. When I used the emulator or real device, the `adView` is not visible. I tried to give height to `adView` like `200 dp`. Then the `adView` is visible. But, when I gave the value of `wrap_content` for the height of the `adView`, there is a problem. I used `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` but the problem is the same. What should I do for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nav_contact_us_content_explanation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="@string/nav_contact_us_content_mail" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adview_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put AdView in FrameLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nav_contact_us_content_explanation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="@string/nav_contact_us_content_mail" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adview_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `LinearLayout`, as the weight was set to `1`, it took the whole screen when the ad was **not yet loaded**. However, you should see a warning like the following in your logcat here.

```
W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x495 dp.
```

In order to fix the problem, you might consider using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adview"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Contact us" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text="Email" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adview_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On the other hand, you might also consider setting up a fixed size for the `AdView` so that it does not hide when the content is not yet loaded. You can get the sizes of different types of ads for different screen sizes [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_sizes).